# The term 'New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I was getting below error

The term '**New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace**' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

If i try to run **Import-Module AzureRM.ServiceBus** I get below error

The member 'FormatsToProcess' in the module manifest is not valid: Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.ServiceBus.\Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.format.ps1xml' because it does not exist.. Please make sure that a valid value is specified for this field in file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.ServiceBus\AzureRM.ServiceBus.psd1'.

As suggested on [Error loading azure.profile in 1.0.5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1919), I reinstalled azure PowerShell using "**Install-Module AzureRM -Verbose -Force**". After that New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace is identified but getting below error

"The term '**Login-AzureRmAccount**' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.".

The solution to fix this error is reinstalling Azure PowerShell by using MSI. After that **Login-AzureRmAccount** is identified but **New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace** goes missing again. I'm going in circles.

I've to make **New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace** work without breaking **Login-AzureRmAccount**. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Azure PowerShell version firstly, you could use the following cmdlet.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

My version is 3.6.0. `New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace` and `Login-AzureRmAccount` all work for me. If your version is not latest, I suggest you could update your version to latest. You can download the PS version 3.6.0 installation file from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Update from comment:

When OP upgrade his laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10, it works fine.

Comment: Azure is 3.5.0 and AzureRm is 3.6.0. Looks like few others also are facing same issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3443. Please let me know how you installed azure powershell (web platform installer, powershell or MSI)? It would be great if you can specify the steps.

Comment: @Venky I install powershell by using MSI(the link I provided you). If you had install Azure Powershell, it will coverage and upgrade original version.

Comment: If i install using MSI then New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace is not available. One of my co-worker has windows 10 and it is working absolutely fine on his machine. My machine has Windows 7. I tried almost everything and for some reason it is not working. I'll upgrade to Windows 10 and then try again. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My laptop got upgraded to windows 10 and it is all working fine now. @Walter Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the Azure powershell that was installed by msi (completely) and reboot, after that I'd check `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` directory and delete all Azure related modules from there. After that, I'd do `Install-Module AzureRM`

Comment: Login-AzureRmAccount is not recognized when azure powershell is installed using Install-Module command.