# The term 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-group

I need to run below command in my PowerShell :

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment 
    -Name Myrg1010 
    -ResourceGroupName ADFcslResourceGroup 
    -TemplateFile C:\ADFARM.json 
    -TemplateParameterFile C:\ADFARM-Parameters.json
```

Before running this command I have connected to my Azure subscribtion

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

But I have below error :

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : The term 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment' is 
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyARMDeployment -ResourceGroupNam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New- 
   AzResourceGroupDeployment:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587582/the-term-new-azurermservicebusnamespace-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmd) but this is not my case because my powershell version is 5.1.2

```
Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     5.1.2      Azure                               {Get- 
AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAuto...
```

Could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: did you install the module Az Resources?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install the Azure Powershell module:

You can look for just the one for this command:

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

Or all of them:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.8.0) for details

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you get a cmdlet error, you need to check if the modules are installed, as mentioned in the comment, try installing

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

[**Az Module**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.8.0)